# Angular 11 problem with loadChildren in routing

Tags: angular, routes

After I log in into my app I go to the link

```
this.router.navigate(['/sellTicket/chooseTicket']);
```

In my app-routing I have following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: HomeComponent, children: [ //todo w AuthGuard trzeba sprawdzic, czy dane logowania poprawne
      {path: 'sellTicket', loadChildren: () => import('./sell-ticket/sell-ticket.module').then(m => m.SellTicketModule)},
    ]},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: false, useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I can see that the Home component is initialized because of the console.log I've put, but, the SellTicketComponent is not. Inside the home.component.html I have

```
<app-header></app-header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I'm not sure what is the problem here. In my sell-ticket-routing.module I have

```
const ticketRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: SellTicketComponent, children: [
            {path: 'chooseTicket', component:ChooseTicketComponent},
            {path: 'chooseTrain', component:ChooseTrainComponent}
        ]}
]

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ticketRoutes)],
exports: [RouterModule]})
export class SellTicketRoutingModule {
}
```

so if the path starts with sellTicket it should load the SellTicketComponent, and then if the folowing path matches it should load propr component as well but it doesnt

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in Stackbliz so that it is easy to understand ?

Comment: something like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6zxo8a?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Yes I posted my answer based on the code now have a look, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I made few changes to the code you posted in stackbliz it is working fine please check if that is what you need or revert back so that I can help you better.

Changes made are added declarations in sell ticket module, Corrected selector used in index.html with the selector in app.component.ts and Modified routing in app module and also added direct routing in sell ticket module.ts file without separate file.

Username: user
Password: test

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pp7r11?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts

Comment: Hello, it's not working properly, when you log in you can see the page not found component, because on the screen you have "Nothing!"

Comment: Ohh sorry comment   this.initRoutes(); in the ngonInit of app.component.ts you can see that working.

Comment: yes it is. But I would like to use the home component, I have a header defined there which should be visible on all screen, After your routing changes there is no home component used any more

Comment: You place the header code above the router-outlet tag of SellTicketComponent then you can see all the sub module component having that header.

Comment: and why the initRoutes in app.component.ts are wrong? I mean in the future I would probably need more routing and then paths would be login, sellTicket, settings,whatever so to make it work I think I would nedd this method here, am I wrong?

Comment: Place all your future routes app.routing.module.ts and if the route belongs to sub module then place in the forRoot method of that module. It is not advised to use reset route config in app component.

Answer (score 0):

In your app-routing.module change *ticketRoutes* in:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
      {path: 'ticket',
      loadChildren: () =>import('./sell-ticket/sell-ticket.module').then(m => m.SellTicketModule)},

  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

And in sell-ticket-module:

```js
const ticketRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: SellTicketComponent},
  {path: 'chooseTicket', component:ChooseTicketComponent},
  {path: 'chooseTrain', component:ChooseTrainComponent}
]
```

Comment: it's still the same

Comment: and if you set useHash: false?

Comment: same, only loading home component, not any one of sellticket/chooseticket/choosetrain

Comment: I edited the answer. can you check? Try ticket/chooseTicket or ticket/chooseTrain

Comment: there is problem with .then "Property 'then' does not exist on type ./sell-ticket/sell-ticket.module' you missed the import statement, but it stil doesnt show chooseTicket component

Comment: Have you created the component in this way? "ng generate module SellTicketComponent --route SellTicketComponent --module app.module".

Comment: you are using LazyLoading

Comment: I've used only ng generate component sell-ticket

Comment: it's strange that doesn't work. I have a similar example and works perfectly. Maybe u missed something in sell.module. Try to generate the lazy modules with  "ng generate module SellTicket --route SellTicket--module app.module". Or publish your example on stackblitz

Comment: I commented earlier link to stackblitz with my code :) take a look

Comment: ant this is my module:

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SellTicketComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SellTicketRoutingModule,
        ChooseTrainModule,
        ChooseTicketModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [SellTicketComponent]
})
export class SellTicketModule{}

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [SellTicketComponent,SellTicketComponent,ChooseTrainComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SellTicketRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class SellTicketModule{ }

Comment: My answer was for loading the "father" component "SellTicketComponent" in lazy loading, and the other 2 components not in lazy loading. If you have modules even for the other 2 child components, it means you need to lazy load even them.

Comment: The stackblitz link is old and isn't yours :). If you publish yours i will take a look

Comment: how come it's old and not mine ? If I go to this link i can see my code on my account... :O
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6zxo8a?file=src/app/app.module.ts